# How to create a table with fixed length inside a scrollView in Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: iphone, titanium, scrollview, tableview

I'm trying to add some imageViews and a tableView into scrollView in Titanium. I want the scrollView to be scrollable but not the tableView inside, so I set tableView.scrollable to false. However, even if the height of the scrollView exceeds the height of the screen, it is not scrollable. Since it's not encouraged to put a tableView inside a scrollView, I'm wondering if there is a better way to create a table with fixed length inside a scrollView in Titanium?

The following is my code:

```
var view = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth:'auto',
    contentHeight:'auto',
    top:0,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator:true,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator:true,
});

var imageview1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: "../images/headers/gscs_logo.png",
    height: 80,
    left: 10,
    right: 10,
    top: 10,
});

var imageview2 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: "../images/headers/wellness_logo.png",
    height: 80,
    left: 10,
    right: 10,
    top: 90,
});

view.add(imageview1);
view.add(imageview2);

var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: [{title:'a'}, {title:'b'}, {title:'c'}, {title:'d'}, {title:'e'}, {title:'f'}, {title:'g'}],
    top: 180,
    scrollable: false,
});

view.add(tableview);

Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(view);
```

[This](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-FoDP-e80lXQ/TsVHCQFHVsI/AAAAAAAAAHQ/g8Gv1elbswk/s800/3.png) is the window I got (StackOverflow does not allow new users to post images, sorry).

[This](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-UZd9jAt3UpI/TsVHB3Ut3tI/AAAAAAAAAHQ/aa0A1nXI020/s800/1.png) is the window I want. The table has fixed number of rows and its parent view can be scrolled.

I have also tried to set currentWindow.layout to "vertical", but that failed since neither the scrollView nor the tableView would show up.

Thank you for your patience and help!

Comment: You shouldn't add a `UITableView` to a `UIScrollView`, as the touch events will not be sent properly.

Comment: @MSgambel I know this is not good, but I can't think of a better solution.

Comment: Try this one, its work for me:
------------------------------[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242298/how-i-can-add-a-table-view-in-a-scroll-view

Comment: Try this one, its work for me:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242298/how-i-can-add-a-table-view-in-a-scroll-view

Comment: **Try this one**
[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242298/how-i-can-add-a-table-view-in-a-scroll-view## Heading ##

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at Kitchen Sink, Titanium's demo app, I figured out how to do this: just set tableview.style to Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED, and and set the imageView as tableview.headerView.

```
var imageview = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: "../images/headers/bakerinstitute_logo.png",
    height: 100,
    left: 40,
    right: 40,
    top: 10,
});

var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: [{title:'a', header:'first one'}, {title:'b'}, {title:'c'}, {title:'d'}, {title:'e'}, {title:'f'}, {title:'g'}, {title:'h'}, {title:'i'}, {title:'j'}, {title:'k', header:'last one'}],
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    rowBackgroundColor:'white',
    headerView: imageview
});

Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(tableview);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should check out the [UICatalog sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) provided by apple. There are many views, and some of them look like the one you provided a link for. Hope that Helps!

Comment: this is about titanium, not objective C

Comment: It's still an example he might be able to use.