# How i can add a table view in a scroll view?

Tags: android, titanium, scrollview, tableview

I am adding a table view in a scroll view, its smoothly working in case of iOS but in case of Android the table view not scrolls.

i have describe the code below which describe my problem..
Suggest me any answer which can help to solve my problem.

```
var rows = [];

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:'white'
});

var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    top : 0,
    contentWidth : '100%',
    contentHeight : 'auto'
});

var fruit = Ti.UI.createView({
    top : 40,
    width : '70%',
    height : 20,
    left : 10,
    backgroundColor:'#000'
});
var fruitLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "Fruit list",
    font:{
        fontSize : 15,
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    color : 'red'
});
fruit.add(fruitLabel);
var fruitTableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    top : 70,
    width : 200,
    height : 150,
    left : 80,
    right : 20,
    separatorColor : 'transparent'
});
rows = [];
for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
    rows.push(Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title:'fruit ' + String(i),
        color : '#000'
    }));
};
fruitTableView.setData(rows);

var veg = Ti.UI.createView({
    top : 250,
    width : '70%',
    height : 20,
    left : 10,
    backgroundColor:'#82C6E8'
});
var vegLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "Veg list",
    font:{
        fontSize : 15,
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    color : 'red'
});
veg.add(vegLabel);
var vegTableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    top : 280,
    width : 200,
    height : 150,
    left : 80,
    right : 20,
});
rows = [];
for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
    rows.push(Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title:'veg ' + String(i),
        color : '#000'
    }));
};
vegTableView.setData(rows);


var grains = Ti.UI.createView({
    top : 460,
    width : '70%',
    height : 20,
    left : 10,
    backgroundColor:'pink'
});
var grainLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "Grains list",
    font:{
        fontSize : 15,
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    color : 'red'
});
grains.add(grainLabel);
var grainsTableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    top : 490,
    width : 200,
    height : 120,
    left : 80,
    right : 20,
});
rows = [];
for(var i=0; i<50; i++){
    rows.push(Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title:'grain ' + String(i),
        color : '#000'
    }));
};
grainsTableView.setData(rows);

scrollableView.add(fruit);
scrollableView.add(fruitTableView);
scrollableView.add(veg);
scrollableView.add(vegTableView);
scrollableView.add(grains);
scrollableView.add(grainsTableView);

win.add(scrollableView);
win.open();
```

Comment: to use tableview insode scrollview is bad idea but i do not your exact requirement so.....

and yes it creates problem when you add table inside scrollview in android so i would suggest to set tableview's exact height..

Comment: @MitulBhalia i also study somewhere that its a bad idea but if you will see my requirement i think there is no other solution except it.
Mitul it works fine in iOS case but it raise problem in Android case.
Have a look to my problem suggest me any way how i can solve my problem in case of Android.

Comment: you should show all the rows of table....
for that you need to set tableview's height to its content height.

Comment: @MitulBhalia first thing is that i have to create dynamic row in table so i don't know height of table in program. and also if i have 50 item in first table and 50 in second table then user have to scroll much to see the item of 3rd table, i think it will be worst UI if i will go with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks guys for your reply,
i found the right way to implement it with the help of @Surajkochale .

Here is the solution of my problem if i add these lines in my code and it works well..

```
fruitTableView.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
    scrollableView.canCancelEvents = false;
});
fruitTableView.addEventListener('touchend', function(){
    scrollableView.canCancelEvents = true;
});
fruitTableView.addEventListener('touchcancel', function(){
    scrollableView.canCancelEvents = true;
});


vegTableView.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
    scrollableView.canCancelEvents = false;
});
vegTableView.addEventListener('touchend', function(){
    scrollableView.canCancelEvents = true;
});
vegTableView.addEventListener('touchcancel', function(){
    scrollableView.canCancelEvents = true;
});


grainsTableView.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
    scrollableView.canCancelEvents = false;
});
grainsTableView.addEventListener('touchend', function(){
    scrollableView.canCancelEvents = true;
});
grainsTableView.addEventListener('touchcancel', function(){
    scrollableView.canCancelEvents = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add tableview in a view...

```
fruit.add(fruitTableView);
scrollableView.add(fruit);

veg.add(vegTableView);
scrollableView.add(veg);

grains.add(grainsTableView);
scrollableView.add(grains);
```

Comment: Hi @Mitul
 Please check once again what you reply. It's not any solution.

Comment: oh..sorry for that.....i though you want to add tableview in a scrollableView but it just a scrollView.

Comment: its ok @MitulBhalia . If u have any other solution let me know

Answer (score 0):

you can check for `contentHeight : Ti.UI.SIZE`, it worked for me

Comment: Hi @Swanand
 My problem is table view not scrolling when i add a table view in a scollview. Scrollview working smooth. So please suggest me any answer how tableview can scroll when adding in a scrollview window.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    bubbleParent:false,
});
```

not smoothly, but it work.

Comment: Yes @Suraj it works but you know if i implement it in my project client will fly immediately and will come near to me to ask what i implement and why ;) :)
Suraj it works but very irritated can u please suggest me any other solution..

Comment: @NeerajGoel you can add tableviews directly to window without scrollview.

Comment: Please read my example carefully, if i will add tableview direct in window then only some part of my will be visible and will be scroll other part will be hidden.
Please read my example once again i hope u will reply me the right way to implement it.

Comment: try this http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView-property-canCancelEvents

Comment: thanks Suraj for your this answer, if i am using this property in a right way it works well...
thanks again for your reply.